# Pyspark filter in Window function based on current rows value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to find the average of a column (hit) partitioned by id but filtering out rows based on the current rows value, in this case i want to filter out rows for each partition whose date is greater than the current rows date.

```
data = [
("456",'0','14-02-2022'),
("456",'1','13-02-2022'),
("123",'0','12-02-2022'),
("456",'0','11-02-2022'),
("123",'1','15-02-2022')]
    
cols = ["id","hit","date"]
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = cols)
```

Expected outcome:

```
+---+---+----------+---------                                                            
| id|hit|      date| avg(hit)
+---+---+----------+---------
|456|  0|14-02-2022| 1/2 (both dates of id 456 are lower than this date)
|456|  1|13-02-2022| 0 (the other date of id 456 is lower, so avg is 0)
|123|  0|12-02-2022| None (there is no record with a lower date of id 123)
|456|  0|11-02-2022| None (there is no record with a lower date of id 456)
|123|  1|15-02-2022| 0 (the other date of id 123 is lower, so avg is 0)
+---+---+----------+---------
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

An `avg` window function that looks at unbounded preceding and 1 row before current row will give you the required outcome.

```
# convert date field to date type
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'hit', 'dt']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.to_date('dt', 'dd-MM-yyyy').cast('date'))

# +---+---+----------+
# | id|hit|        dt|
# +---+---+----------+
# |456|  0|2022-02-14|
# |456|  1|2022-02-13|
# |123|  0|2022-02-12|
# |456|  0|2022-02-11|
# |123|  1|2022-02-15|
# +---+---+----------+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('hit_avg',
               func.avg('hit').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('dt').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, -1))
               ). \
    show()

# +---+---+----------+-------+
# | id|hit|        dt|hit_avg|
# +---+---+----------+-------+
# |456|  0|2022-02-11|   null|
# |456|  1|2022-02-13|    0.0|
# |456|  0|2022-02-14|    0.5|
# |123|  0|2022-02-12|   null|
# |123|  1|2022-02-15|    0.0|
# +---+---+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!

What if i need to compare the date of the current row with another date col?
Say dt of the current row needs to be higher than dt2?

E.g. lets create another col dt2 and set it to 2022-02-20. 
The expected result of "hit_avg2" would be NULL in every case because there is no dt that is higher than dt2 (2022-02-20)? Is that possible?

Comment: a window won't help there. you can, however, use joins or other methodologies. would be good to have that as a new question.

Comment: Yea, thats what i was thinking.
I created a new Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192180/pyspark-aggregate-on-partitions-with-a-conditional-filter-based-on-current-rows

Comment: Note this will not work if you have multiple rows with the same date, since `rowBetween` only cares about the order not the actual values. Additionally I would use `Window.unboundedPreceding` not sys.maxsize.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way (using lag to get the shifted average you require):

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("date").asc())
df = df.withColumn("avg", F.lag(
    F.avg("hit").over(w)
).over(w))
```