# Pyspark aggregate on partitions with a conditional filter based on current rows column a values and partitions column b values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to find the average of a column (hit) partitioned by id but filtering out rows based on the current rows value in column date with values of the partition in column date2.
In this case i want to filter out rows for each partition whose dt2 is greater than the current rows dt.

```
data = [
("456",'0','14-02-2022','20-02-2022'),
("456",'1','13-02-2022','20-02-2022'),
("456",'0','11-02-2022','20-02-2022'),
("123",'1','15-02-2022','01-02-2022')
("123",'0','12-02-2022','20-02-2022')
]
    
cols = ["id","hit","date","date2"]
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = cols)
```

Expected outcome:

```
+---+---+----------+----------+-------+                                         
| id|hit|        date|       date2|hit_avg|
+---+---+----------+----------+-------+
|456|  0|2022-02-14|2022-02-20|   null (every other dt2 of partition 456 is higher than this dt)|
|456|  1|2022-02-13|2022-02-20|   null (every other dt2 of partition 456 is higher than this dt)|
|456|  0|2022-02-11|2022-02-20|   null (every other dt2 of partition 456 is higher than this dt)|
|123|  1|2022-02-15|2022-02-01|   null (every other dt2 of partition 123 is higher than this dt)|
|123|  0|2022-02-12|2022-02-20|   1 (there is one other record of partition 123 where dt2<dt of this row)
+---+---+----------+----------+-------+
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: will `date2` always be same for a partition or can they have different records?

Comment: no, it can be different every time
e.g. see row 4 and 5, same partition/ids, different date2

Comment: why did you write `"every other dt2 of partition 123 is higher than this dt"` in the second last row? '2022-02-01' is lower than both dates in `date` column for partition "123".

Comment: I want to compare dt of the current row with dt2 of the other rows.
In the second last row, it is dt=2022-02-15. 
dt2 of the partition 123 (last row) is higher (2022-02-20) than dt of row 4 --> result should be null

Comment: so, in the last row for partition "123", all dates excluding the last row in `date2` should be considered. correct? (let's say there were 3 records for partition "123")

Comment: So for the last row date= 2022-02-12 and date2=2022-02-20

I need to take the date of this row (2022-02-12) and check for all rows with id=123
if date2 of these other rows is smaller than date of the last row

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with inequality join. It's certainly not the best possible way, but it should be fine for smaller datasets.

```
# input dataframe -- convert date fields to date type
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'hit', 'dt', 'dt2']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.to_date('dt', 'dd-MM-yyyy').cast('date')). \
    withColumn('dt2', func.to_date('dt2', 'dd-MM-yyyy').cast('date'))

# +---+---+----------+----------+
# | id|hit|        dt|       dt2|
# +---+---+----------+----------+
# |456|  0|2022-02-14|2022-02-20|
# |456|  1|2022-02-13|2022-02-20|
# |123|  0|2022-02-12|2022-02-20|
# |456|  0|2022-02-11|2022-02-20|
# |123|  1|2022-02-15|2022-02-01|
# |123|  0|2022-02-16|2022-02-02|  # I've added this row in this example
# +---+---+----------+----------+
```

You do a self join on `id` field, but provide the unequal logic of the dates. The dataframe post join would look like the following.

```
data_sdf. \
    select('id', 'dt', func.col('hit').alias('hit_a')). \
    alias('a'). \
    join(data_sdf.withColumnRenamed('hit', 'hit_b').alias('b'), 
         [func.col('a.id') == func.col('b.id'), 
          func.col('a.dt') != func.col('b.dt'), 
          func.col('dt2') < func.col('a.dt')], 
         'left'
         ). \
    drop(func.col('b.id')). \
    show()

# the second `dt` is of `b` dataframe
# +---+----------+-----+-----+----------+----------+
# | id|        dt|hit_a|hit_b|        dt|       dt2|
# +---+----------+-----+-----+----------+----------+
# |456|2022-02-14|    0| null|      null|      null|
# |456|2022-02-13|    1| null|      null|      null|
# |456|2022-02-11|    0| null|      null|      null|
# |123|2022-02-12|    0|    1|2022-02-15|2022-02-01|
# |123|2022-02-12|    0|    0|2022-02-16|2022-02-02|
# |123|2022-02-15|    1|    0|2022-02-16|2022-02-02|
# |123|2022-02-16|    0|    1|2022-02-15|2022-02-01|
# +---+----------+-----+-----+----------+----------+
```

For the date `2020-02-12`, excluding that row's `dt2` values, there are 2 ther values of `dt2` that are lower than `2020-02-12`. Hence, both of them get mapped to that `dt` value. We can take an average of the `hit_b` field, grouped at `id` and `dt` fields.

```
data_sdf. \
    select('id', 'dt', func.col('hit').alias('hit_a')). \
    alias('a'). \
    join(data_sdf.withColumnRenamed('hit', 'hit_b').alias('b'), 
         [func.col('a.id') == func.col('b.id'), func.col('a.dt') != func.col('b.dt'), func.col('dt2') < func.col('a.dt')], 
         'left'
         ). \
    drop(func.col('b.id')). \
    drop(func.col('b.dt')). \
    groupBy('id', 'dt'). \
    agg(func.avg('hit_b').alias('hit_avg')). \
    show()

# +---+----------+-------+
# | id|        dt|hit_avg|
# +---+----------+-------+
# |456|2022-02-14|   null|
# |456|2022-02-13|   null|
# |456|2022-02-11|   null|
# |123|2022-02-12|    0.5|
# |123|2022-02-15|    0.0|
# |123|2022-02-16|    1.0|
# +---+----------+-------+
```